# StructureMap - check if instance of some class/interface has been already created

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have the need to check if an instance of some interface has already been created by structuremap. I have tried ObjectFactory.GetInstance() but this creates a new instance of T when called and a concrete instance of T does not exist. I just want to check if an instance of T has already been created (not to create a new). I need this to force the creation of instances through a certain class).

Comment: I'm curious, could you explain why you need to do this? If you need to discover if an instance has been created, perhaps this indicates that you're trying to manage a singleton, which StructureMap can be configured to do automatically.

Comment: I am trying to force the creation of an NHibernate Session through a specific class (open & close transactions, disposing, etc). This class is created by means of property injection. All other classes (repositories) should only be able to get an ISession which is already created. So I need I call to some structuremap function that only gets an already created ISession object, otherwise it should throw an error or return null. ... And the Session is http context based, not a singleton.

Comment: Maybe you could do this by creating a new repository-like class that controls access to your unique NHibernate Session (which lets you check if it's been created yet and create it explicitly) and have StructureMap inject this repository-type object as a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ask StructureMap if it has already created an instance of an interface.

However, it does have many lifecycle management features that allow it to control whether it creates a new instance, or returns a cached instance that it previously created.

You can tell StructureMap to make an instance HttpContextScoped, so that it returns the same instance for a given HTTP request.

It sounds like what you really want to know is how to handle NHibernate sessions in a web application with StructureMap. Try:
http://trason.net/journal/2009/10/7/bootstrapping-nhibernate-with-structuremap.html

Comment: Thks Joshua. Figured out by now that it's not possible. You mention though that it is possible to "control whether structuremap creates a new instance, or returns a cached instance that it previously created". If this is true, I can i.e. try to get a cached instance. If it's not in the container, I should get a null object. Can you pls give a small code snippet how to do this. As for my NHibernate problem, I have solved it checking if a transaction is open (the transaction gets opened only in one location).

Comment: As for the example you mention, I did see it already before. I based my previous session management on a similar sample, but I didn't like the fact that it creates a NHibernate session fore every web request. I tried Ayende's NHibernate profiler (trial version) and was shocked to see how many NHibernate sessions were created (even if such a session is rather lightweigth). A session was created even for static jpeg gets.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this using:

```
ObjectFactory.Model.InstancesOf<IYourInterface>().First().ObjectHasBeenCreated();
```

Note, this only works for instances with Singleton, HttpContext or Hybrid lifecycle.